# All prime ideals of $R/I$ where $R$ is the infinite polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**Problem:**

> Let $R = k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the polynomial ring over a
>   field $k$ in infinitely many variables. Let $I = \langle x_1, x_2^2,
>  x_3^3, \ldots \rangle$ be an ideal of $R$.
>
> Find: 
>  (a) all the prime ideals of $R/I$.
>
> b) Show that $R/I$ is not noetherian.

**Attempt:** For b), I think I found the infinite ascending chain $$ \langle x_1 \rangle + I \subset \langle x_1, x_2 \rangle + I \subset \ldots $$ which shows $R/I$ is not noetherian.

For a), I was not sure. How does one solve these kinds of problems? I was thinking that all ideals of the form $$ \langle x_1 \rangle + I, \qquad \langle x_2 \rangle + I, \ldots $$ are surely prime. For if $$fg \in \langle x_i \rangle + I $$ then at least $f$ or $g$ must be divided by $x_i$ I think.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: How can you relate (prime) ideals of a quotient ring with (prime) ideals of the base ring ?

Comment: By the way, $(x_1), (x_1x_2), (x_1x_2x_3),\cdots$ is not an ascending chain of ideals. It's a descending chain of ideals.

Comment: Ah you are right. So what I have shown it is not artinian. I need to show it is not noetherian though.

Comment: $R/I$ would be noetherian if and only if every prime ideal is finitely generated. So I need to show the prime ideals are not finitely generated.

Comment: Hint: Here, $k$ is a field and hence, commutative. Therefore, $P$ is a prime ideal iff $R/P$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any prime ideal of the quotient ring $R/I$ can be seen as a prime ideal of $R$ containing $I$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be such a prime ideal. As an ideal of $R$, it must contain every element $x_k^k$ for $k\in \mathbb N$. Because the ideal $\mathfrak p$ is prime, it means that it actually contains every single variable $x_k$.
Whence, there is only one prime ideal in $R/I$, which can be seen as the ideal generated by all the variables in $R$. Note that it is indeed a prime (and even maximal) ideal since the quotient of $R$ by it is no other than $k$.
Because this prime ideal is not finitely generated, the quotient ring $R/I$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: I don't understand your first assertion. Is this always true? The relationship between prime ideals in $R$ and in $R/I$? Can you prove this.

Comment: @Kamil Use $4$th Isomorphism Theorem for Rings. (More precisely, it is called Correspondance Theorem for Rings.)

Comment: @Kamil It is indeed always true for any ring $R$ and any ideal $I$. Let $\pi$ be the projection morphism from $R$ to $R/I$. The statement is "The map $J \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(J)$ induces a bijection between the set of ideals of $R/I$ to the set of ideals of $R$ containing $I$. This bijection preserves prime (and maximal) ideals". Mostly, this statement only makes use of the definitions, I advise you to try and prove it. =)

Comment: Ahh, I know what statement you mean. But I didn't know it preserves maximal/prime ideals. Good to know.

Comment: I have a final question. Why must $\mathfrak{p}$ contain elements of the form $x_k^{k}$? Is it because $\mathfrak{p}$ must contain $I$?

Comment: @Kamil Yes, exactly. The ideal $I$ is generated by the elements $x_k^k$ by definition, and $I$ is contained in $\mathfrak p$.