# Is a ring whose every descending chain of prime ideals stabilizes, necessary Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

It is know that the DCC on prime ideals holds in Noetherian rings (see e.g., [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584524/is-it-true-that-in-a-noetherian-ring-every-descending-chain-of-prime-ideals-stab)). I ask whether the converse holds: Is a commutative ring whose every descending chain of prime ideals stabilizes Noetherian?

Comment: No, this is not true. Here is an example of a non Noetherian ring which has only $1$ prime ideal (and so your condition trivially holds there): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298442/all-prime-ideals-of-r-i-where-r-is-the-infinite-polynomial-ring/3298454

Comment: No, by the simple reason of the definition involves ascending and descending chaines.

Comment: @Mark, why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Piquito. Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @MikeTeX I can write it as an answer as well.

Comment: @MikeTeX: If the definition take into account both ascending and descending chaines, one of them is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Here you can see an example of a non Noetherian ring which has exactly one prime ideal, and so your condition trivially holds there.

[All prime ideals of $R/I$ where $R$ is the infinite polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298442/all-prime-ideals-of-r-i-where-r-is-the-infinite-polynomial-ring/3298454)

Answer (score 1):

The ring of [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) is an example of a non-Noetherian ring with Krull dimension $1$, and so it would not have long chains of prime ideals.

Another example is an infinite direct product of fields: such a ring is von Neumann regular, and so it has Krull dimension $0$, but if it has infinitely many factors then it is not Noetherian.